# La bonne façon de répondre à des questions sur la prononciation

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

> Pronounciation questions

Je propose de déconseiller fortement d'expliquer de prononciations françaises avec de comparaisons aux mots anglais, au moins, de ne pas utiliser cela comme seule explication.

D'après expérience, ils existent des mots anglais qui sont systématiquement mal prononcés et avec conviction (par exemple: *duck*).

Je suggère donc: de faire plutôt des comparaisons avec d'autres mots français dont la prononciation peut être trouvée dans des fichiers audio sur le web, l'utilisation de vocabulaire précis et d'utilisation d'IPA. (API??)

Translation:
I suggest to strongly discourage the explanation of French pronounciations by comparison with English words. At the very least, this should not be used as the only explanation.

In my experience, there are English words who are malpronounced systematically and with conviction (e.g. duck).

Therefore, I'd prefer: comparisons with other French words whose pronounciation is found in audio files on the web, usage of exact vocabulary (e.g. open, nasal, ...) and usage of IPA.

Comment: English translation, please. See: http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/38/can-stack-exchange-employees-understand-french/70#70

Comment: @Robert: can't edit the question, so here is a rough translation: I propose to strongly discourage to explaine French prononciation by ucomparing it to English words; or at the very least not to use this as sole answer. In my experience, there are English words which are systematically mispronounced, and with conviction (such as duck). I would thus prefer: comparisons with other French words for which there are audio proncounciation on the web, usage of adequate and precise vocabulary, and usage of the IPA

Answer (score 10):

1. Je soutiens fortement la proposition de déconseiller la pronciation par rapprochement, sauf peut-être par recours au rimes (par exemple, “*thyme* rimes with *time*” est plus court et plus clair que d'écrire en IPA).
2. Oui à l'IPA ! On peut aussi demander à StackExchange de fournir une police IPA comme ils le font pour les maths.
3. Mettons dans la FAQ un lien vers une description claire en français et en anglais des symboles IPA utilisés pour la prononciation française (plutôt que la liste complète). Si besoin, compilons nous-même cette liste.
4. Un détail: la prononciation IPA est entre crochets [kroʃɛ] dans les ouvrages de référence francophones que j'ai (contrairement à l'usage des slash sur EL&U).

Comment: Il n'y a pas besoin de support spécifique pour les symboles IPA, ils sont tous dans Unicode.

Comment: @Gilles: tout le monde n'a pas des polices Unicode complètes. Le navigateur pourrait fournir une police *fallback* (voir [ici](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1027))

Comment: Je vois que le CNRTL propose des fichiers audios, c'est peut-être aussi une piste pour les problèmes de prononciation  http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/abrévié - enfin, pas tous les problèmes... http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/poutine  (Je ne sais pas écouter les fichiers sons d'ici, est-ce qu'ils sont bons?)

Comment: Pour 4. En phonologie les crochets servent à indiquer une prononciation exacte (e.g. pour la différence de son entre [meta] et [mɛta]) et les slash une séquence de phonèmes (où /meta/ et /mɛta/ seraient équivalents en français standard). https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Phonology#Representing_phonemes

Answer (score 3):

IPA works for me, and is used all the time on English Language & Usage, in the format:

> /'lɪ.nəks/

Comment: IPA notation is a little different in French, see [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international). I very strongly recommend to always use [krɔʃɛdrwa] for French pronunciation and /slæʃĭz/ for English pronunciation if it ever comes up.

Answer (score 2):

La manière recommandée pour noter la prononciation est l'[alphabet phonétique international](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_international). L'article de Wikipedia sur la [prononciation du français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais) a liste des symboles utilisés en français. Je recommande de consulter Wikipedia qui a notamment une correspondance entre les symboles IPA et les noms techniques (par exemple, la prononciation habituelle de la lettre U se note [[y](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_y)] et s'appelle une [voyelle haute antérieure arrondie](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_haute_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie)).

Cela dit, l'API n'est pas parlant pour beaucoup de monde, donc il vaut mieux donner aussi des exemples de mots courants. Lorsqu'il s'agit de signifier quelles sont les lettres muettes, il n'est pas absurde de proposer un mot anglais ressemblant. Par contre, bien sûr, s'il s'agit de voyelles, il n'y a pas grand-chose à tirer d'une analogie entre les sons des deux langues.

---

Summary: the recommended notation for pronunciation is IPA. The symbols for French are easiest to find on the [French pronunciation page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononciation_du_fran%C3%A7ais). However many people aren't familiar with IPA, so alternate methods can make sense: examples of common words, rhyming English words to indicate which letters are mute (but not when vowels are involved)…